# API Endpoint URL Difference between resourceName/create [POST] vs resourceName [POST]

Tags: api, design-patterns, backend, endpoint

I would like to know whether it's better to use

```
sku/article/create [POST]
```

or

```
/sku/article [POST]
```

In the first URL I specify the action; is that considered a good practice? I've seen both been used consistently. Do people specify action specifically to increase code readability? What is the purpose of it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're attempting to design [level 3](https://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) APIs, then the HTTP verbs indicate the actions; ie. `POST` is an action, usually implied to mean *create.* Thus, the first alternative is redundant.

You usually see common combinations of supported verbs. For instance, a resource that supports `POST` and `GET` is a 'collection' resource, because you can add to it with `POST`, and you can see the entire collection with `GET`, including the one you just created with `POST`.